# RestKit removes path when it makes calls

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, restkit

Why is RestKit removing my path when making API calls? It shows it is good until the call.

**This is how I am registering it**

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"apiURL"]]];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:RKMIMETypeJSON];
[client setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];
NSLog(@"Created client: %@", objectManager.HTTPClient);
```

**This is how I call it in other classes**

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
NSLog(@"HTTP Client: %@", manager.HTTPClient);
```

Even in other classes where I call the shared objectManager it is correct, but I get logging during the calls and a bad response because the `/api/v1` is taken out.

**NSLOG**

```
2013-03-13 13:24:08.960 Project[54631:403] HTTP Client: <AFHTTPClient: 0x1033d6230, baseURL: https://my.server.com/api/v1/, defaultHeaders: {
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Accept-Language" = "en, ja, fr, de, es, it, pt, pt-PT, nl, sv, nb, da, fi, ru, pl, zh-Hans, zh-Hant, ko, ar, cs, hu, tr, en-us;q=0.8";
    Authorization = "Bearer <My Access Token>";
    "User-Agent" = "Project/1.0 (Mac OS X Version 10.7.5 (Build 11G63))";
}, registeredOperationClasses: (
), operationQueue: <NSOperationQueue: 0x1033db8c0>{name = 'NSOperationQueue 0x1033db8c0'}>
2013-03-13 13:24:08.960 Project[54631:403] Manager: <RKObjectManager: 0x1033db940>
2013-03-13 13:24:08.971 Project[54631:403] I restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:154 GET 'https://my.server.com/features/1234?with_lock=false'
2013-03-13 13:24:09.310 Project[54631:403] I restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:185 GET 'https://my.server.com/features/1234?with_lock=false' (200 OK)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you ever set a baseUrl to the RESTKIt - Instance? 
You make a

```
[[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client]
```

new instance.

But later you call

```
[RKObjectManager sharedManager]
```

Try first to initialize a shared RKobject e.g.: 
    [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:...
And than use the shared instance rather to create new AFHTTPClient objects.

Comment: I had tried `[RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:]` and it wasn't keeping the httpclient when I called `[sharedManager]`. Also the initWithHTTPClient sets the sharedManager.

Comment: Like TClaus already said it seems like your configuration seems to be wrong. You don't need to set the `AFHTTPClient` like you did. Simple set up the RKObjectManager with a base url and access the client (e.g. for the headers) with `[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient`.

Comment: Checkout my answer, the problem is probably your absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it up like this, it works for me:

```
static NSString *BASE_URL = @"http://www.yourdomain.com/api/v2";
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL]];
[objectManager postObject:rating path:@"ratings" parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];
```

The problem was for me that I was providing an absolute path: e.g. @"/ratings" instead of @"ratings".